# Adyen Web Drop In - production unable to load payment form

Tags: vb.net, adyen

0

I've gone through most of the instructions here and am able to process a test card transaction https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in. I pulled down the example repo here https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-dotnet-online-payments.

I adapted it to my own Adyen account and it works when running it under the 'test' Adyen configuration.

However when pushing this to production, it errors at the point when it's calling

Dim CreateCheckoutSessionResponse = _checkout.Sessions(sessionsRequest)

```
 <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True), ScriptMethod()>
    Public Shared Function GetPaymentForm() As Object

        Dim orderId As String = HttpContext.Current.Session("OrderID")

        Dim _connString As String = Config.StrWebConnection()
        Dim cart As New ShoppingCart(_connString)
        Dim dt = cart.GetOrderInfo(orderId)

        Dim isGlobal = IsGlobalSite(Config.SiteUrl)
        Dim liveEndpointUrlPrefix = If(Config.LiveEndpointUrlPrefix = "", Nothing, Config.LiveEndpointUrlPrefix)
        Dim env = If(Int32.Parse(Config.AdyenEnvironment) = 0, Model.Enum.Environment.Test, Model.Enum.Environment.Live)

        Dim clientCheckout = New Client(Config.ApiKey, env, liveEndpointUrlPrefix)
        Dim _checkout = New Checkout(clientCheckout)

        Dim cartTotal = Utilities.SanitizeCurrency(GetCartTotal(orderId, HttpContext.Current.Session("user_name")))

        Dim sessionsRequest = New CreateCheckoutSessionRequest()

        sessionsRequest.MerchantAccount = Config.MerchantAccount(0)
        sessionsRequest.MerchantOrderReference = orderId
        Dim Amount = New Amount("USD", Convert.ToInt64(String.Format("{0:f2}", cartTotal).Replace(".", String.Empty)))
        sessionsRequest.Amount = Amount
        sessionsRequest.DeliverAt = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        sessionsRequest.ExpiresAt = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK"))
        sessionsRequest.ShopperEmail = dt.Email
        sessionsRequest.ShopperLocale = "en-us"

        sessionsRequest.ShopperReference = HttpContext.Current.Session("ShopperReference").ToString().ToUpper()
        sessionsRequest.Channel = PaymentRequest.ChannelEnum.Web
        sessionsRequest.Reference = String.Format("ClientSite_{0}", orderId)
        sessionsRequest.RecurringProcessingModel = CreateCheckoutSessionRequest.RecurringProcessingModelEnum.CardOnFile 'req.IsRecurring ? CreateCheckoutSessionRequest.RecurringProcessingModelEnum.Subscription : CreateCheckoutSessionRequest.RecurringProcessingModelEnum.CardOnFile;
        sessionsRequest.EnableRecurring = False 'req.IsRecurring
        sessionsRequest.EnableOneClick = True '!req.IsRecurring

        'required for 3ds2 redirect flow
        sessionsRequest.ReturnUrl = Config.SiteUrl & "/Confirm.aspx?"

        Dim json As String
        Try
            Dim CreateCheckoutSessionResponse = _checkout.Sessions(sessionsRequest)
            json = CreateCheckoutSessionResponse.ToJson()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Return 0
        End Try
        Return json
    End Function
```

The **liveEndpointUrlPrefix** is set to the full Live Adyen API endpoint. The API key is also the one used from my Adyen API credentials. My environment is set to 'live'. I have also added this site to my allow origins in the API credential.

Lastly, when I step through the code it fails when calling the _checkout.Sessions(sessionRequest) and produces the following error:

```
{System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'https'" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()" & vbCrLf & "   at Adyen.HttpClient.HttpUrlConnectionClient.Request(String endpoint, String json, Config config, Boolean isApiKeyRequired, RequestOptions requestOptions)" & vbCrLf & "   at Adyen.Service.ServiceResource.Request(String json, RequestOptions requestOptions)" & vbCrLf & "   at Adyen.Service.Checkout.Sessions(CreateCheckoutSessionRequest createCheckoutSessionRequest)" & vbCrLf & "   at clients_site.Confirm.GetPaymentForm() in C:\www\Confirm.aspx.vb:line 70}
```

When I change the Adyen credentials to my test Adyen, the payment form loads fine.

Any ideas please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `sessions` call fail, it looks like it cannot resolve to the specified hostname. Can you check the connectivity from your server to the Adyen live environment?

Comment: Do you have already applied for a `live` account? The `live` API credentials (and keys) are different

Comment: We have a live account already and I've set my live api credentials correctly.

Comment: There is connectivity to the adyen live API. When loading it, it prompts for a password meaning that there is no firewall blocking it.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. Given the error is on PROD only it is best to contact Adyen support directly (they will be able to help). Unless we can reproduce the same error on TEST somehow